# Use colorbar for non type object

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, colorbar

I currently try to modify a plot in a python2.7 code. This plot come from a radiative transfert code (what I can't modify), and the output is a class type with a method :

```
plot_image(wavelength0, overplot=False, inclination=None, cmap=None, 
          ax=None, axes_units='AU', polarization=False, polfrac=False, 
          psf_fwhm=None, vmin=None, vmax=None, dynamic_range=1000000.0)
```

more informations [here](http://www.stsci.edu/~mperrin/software/mcfostpy/modelresults.html)

So, when I put a `plt.title()` or `plt.savefig()` just after that, I call the respective method and the title of the plot changes and the plot is saved, as expected!

However, there is two things that I didn't find a way to do it :

1. Add a colorbar
2. trace the surface in log-scale

because no arguments in the method allow to do it.
When I try something like `plt.colorbar(fig)` with `fig=res.plot_image(...)` (with res the class, output of radiative transfert code) the error said that fig is not a mappable object (seems logic).

Any ideas that could help me ? hope I gave you enough informations.

Sorry for my English

Lo_du

Comment: What is the return type of `plot_image`? Can you report what `unknown = res.plot_image(...)` `print type(unknown)` results in?

Comment: [The code from that `plot_image` function](https://github.com/cpinte/mcfost-python/blob/master/mcfost/plotting.py) seems to be quite straight forward, so one can also easily copy and adapt it to one's needs.

Answer (score 0):

If `res.plot_image(...)` only plots one image to one axes, the solution to obtain a colorbar might be pretty easy.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#.... some code

res.plot_image(...)

im, = plt.gca().get_images()

plt.colorbar(im)

plt.show()
```